# How to prevent access to web app that is intended for embedding?

Tags: javascript, html, security, embed

I have a web app `http://embed.myapp.com` that is intended to be embedded on a few whitelisted sites. The frame access is controlled with `X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM`

However, I do not want users to access it by putting in the above link directly in the web browser.

What is the best way to block plain (non-embedded) access?

I can determine whether the site is embedded with javascript, but by that point a session is already created and certain sensitive information such as CSRF tokens can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not quite get an absolutely foolproof way of stopping users from looking at the content directly.

A simple way to catch most cases would be to look at the referer header ( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html section 14.36) on the server side and only serve the content when it is referred from the correct pages.

Comment: Is it common for users/browsers to disable referer header? If the request comes in without a referer header, how do I know whether the header was simply disabled or whether the user is trying to look at the content directly?

Comment: It is not common for the referer header to be disabled from browser traffic but users can certainly use curl to bypass this measure.  It isn't foolproof by any means but it would stop a large proportion of unwanted traffic.  Edit: Remember that anyone can just look at the code using chrome dev tools so you can't really stop access to it.